# Change name in x-ticks (strings) with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am just starting with Matplotlib, and I want to create a simple bar plot with summarized data (I am using Jupyter Notebooks). The data are as follows:

From a Pandas data frame:

```
by_gender = df.groupby(["Gender"])["Value"].mean().reset_index()
```

Result upon which I want to create the bar plot:

```
Gender  Value
0   F   22.936350
1   M   15.897205
```

The code goes as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = by_gender["Gender"]
y = by_gender["Value"]
plt.bar(x, y, label = "Proportion", color = "#468499")
plt.title("% respondents accepting violence against women, by gender")
plt.xlabel("Gender")
plt.ylabel("Proportion %")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This gives me the plot, no problem. But now I want to change the x-ticks from "F" and "M" to "Female" and "Male."

I have googled A LOT, and tried all the functions I have found, including:

```
plt.xticks()
plt.set_ticks()
plt.set_xticks()
plt.set_xticklabels()
```

...and it gives me the same error no matter what:

```
 AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'set_xticks'
```

(substitute "set_xticks" for anything I proposed above)

I tried changing the intervals of the y-axis ticks just for kicks, and it gave me the same error. Is there anything wrong with how I am creating the plot? I also tried creating a subplot, creating the variable fig...and nothing helps.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I keep getting the same error :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should manipulate the axis instead, as in:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(x, y, label = "Proportion", color = "#468499")
ax.set_title("% respondents accepting violence against women, by gender")
ax.set_xlabel("Gender")
ax.set_ylabel("Proportion %")
ax.legend()
ax.set_xticklabels(['Female', 'Male'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: I tried adding the first line as you suggested and it worked! However, when I tried making the other changes (adding ax. to the other commands), it started throwing errors. The only one that I keep with ax. was the ax.set_xticklabels(). Not sure why. Anyway! My problem is solved, so THANK YOU!

Comment: @Daltoniana, I'm glad to hear it worked! Please notice that besides adding ax. to the other commands you have to set the " set_" as well (e.g., plt.title became ax.set_title). Using the axis object for all edits in the chart will make the code more consistent, which amounts to better code.

Also, it would be great if you could make my reply as the answer, as will give me some points that unlock some functionalities in Stackoverflow.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you! Yes, I will do that.